# How to hide remove extra request body parameters in Swagger with Springfox

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have very big UserDto having many fields as below:

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String emailId;
    @Column
    private String password;

    .... many other columns like above with getter/setter
}
```

I have defined authenticate method as below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "authenticate", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ApiOperation(value="authenticate user",notes="authenticate user for all roles")
        @ApiResponses( {
            @ApiResponse( code = 403, message = "BAD_CREDENCIAL_EXCEPTION",response=ExceptionMsgDto.class),
            @ApiResponse( code = 404, message = "USERNAME_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION",response=ExceptionMsgDto.class)
        } )
        public ResponseEntity<Object> authenticate(@RequestBody UserDto userDto, HttpServletRequest request)
                throws Exception {
  /* business logic */
}
```

when I generate swagger it shows all the properties of Userdto inside request model but I want to show only username/password and want to hide others. but at the same point for createUser method I want to show all properties from UserDto.

I tried to find solution but didn't get any, is this possible to do? Please suggest me some way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should have been better of using DTOs that are specific to the request e.g InsertUserDTO, UpdateUserDTO etc..and obviously should contain no methods except for maybe simple gettes/setters.

In my case what I did since I didn't want to add another abstraction layer over my Domain Objects (I pass those in the Controller methods) I just wanted to hide the properties on specific request types so they don't show on Swagger (ver 2.6.1).

Here is what I did:

My Domain Object:

```
public class Entity {
   private String name;
   private String hideThis;

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

   public String getHideThis() { return hideThis; }
   public void setHideThis(String hideThis) { this.hideThis= hideThis; }
}
```

I annotate all the properties I want to be hidden! Works even with private properties :)

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
public class EntityInsertRequest extends Entity {    

   @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
   private User hideThis;

}
```

This way I can control how exactly the request body looks in swagger ui. It can be different for insert/update/delete. Of course this doesn't prevent the user from sending something that will still be serialized! The documentation of the api is clean without the extra layer of DTOs assuming you are guarded from random values/objects being passed to the backend.

Here is my controller method before:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "entity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Entity storeEntity(@RequestBody final Entity in) {

    return entityService.store(in);
}
```

and here is my controller method after:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "entity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Entity storeEntity(@RequestBody final EntityInsertRequest in) {

   return entityService.store(in);
}
```